# Revoke app access to Google Drive file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I use the Google Drive API v3 to manage backup files with my Python app.

The used scope is **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file** which allows only access to files I added with my app.

Is there a way to revoke the app access to files in that way, that they cannot be modified anymore by my app? (especially that they cannot be deleted by the app)

.

**Formulated differently:**

The used scope is described as

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app

Once I opened a file with any app, can I revoke access of this app to the specific file?